# C# MDI - Hide MDI Scrollbars after MDI resize when MDIChild is out of bounds

Tags: c#, scrollbar, mdi, wndproc, mdiparent

I have a MDI Parent (**Form1**) and a MDI Child (**Form2**). I have currently disabled scroll bars for *Form1* when *Form2* goes past the bounds of *Form1* by placing the following code within Form2:

```
protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
{
    const int WM_MOVE = 0x0003;

    switch (m.Msg)
    {
        case WM_MOVE:
            return;

        default:
            base.WndProc(ref m);
            break;
    }
}
```

While the scroll bars for *Form1* will not show if *Form2* goes out of bounds when the user drags *Form2* out of *Form1*'s bounds. It will however show the scroll bars if the user **resizes** *Form1* to where *Form2* goes out of bounds.

How can I fix it so that this does not occur

Comment: WM_SIZE reports that.  This is a Really Bad Idea.  At least move the child windows instead of swallowing messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a work-able solution for myself for now. On the MDI Form (Form1). I use the following code. It at least help's to get rid of the flickering.

```
    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll")]

    private static extern int ShowScrollBar(IntPtr hWnd, int wBar, int bShow);

    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        const int WM_MOVE = 0x0003;
        const int WM_ENTERSIZEMOVE = 0x0231;
        const int WM_EXITSIZEMOVE = 0x0232;
        const int SB_BOTH = 3;

        switch (m.Msg)
        {
            // Use SuspendLayout() instead of having constant flickering on resize starting
            case WM_ENTERSIZEMOVE:
                this.SuspendLayout();
                base.WndProc(ref m);
                break;

            // Do not forget to ResumeLayout() when resizing finished
            case WM_EXITSIZEMOVE:
                this.ResumeLayout();
                base.WndProc(ref m);
                break;

            default:
                ShowScrollBar(this.Handle, SB_BOTH, 0);
                base.WndProc(ref m);
                break;
        }
    }
```